# Print unicode strings in C

Tags: c, windows, unicode, printf

I have a file with sentences like these: `returnCodeMsgDE=Es gibt nicht genug Arbeitsspeicher um das Programm auszuf\u00FChren. Zurzeit gibt es %d frei MB zu verf\u00FCgung`

I want to read these sentences, write them to a variable which will be passed to MessageBox, so I can write them into a dialog window, where the unicode symbols should be substituted by their unicode-equivalent local characters.

But the dialog boxes I get are with the text like this: "auszuf\u00FChren".

This is the part of my code where this situation happens:

```
_TCHAR*   errorMsg = NULL;

_TCHAR* returnCodeMsgDE2 = readPropertiesFile(_T_ECLIPSE("returnDE")); //here I get this string: L"returnCodeMsgDE=Es gibt nicht genug Arbeitsspeicher um das Programm auszuf\\u00FChren. Zurzeit gibt es %d frei MB zu verf\\u00FCgung"

_stprintf(errorMsg, _T_ECLIPSE("%s"), returnCodeMsgDE2, _freeMemory()); //freememory() returns an Integer.


MessageBox( topWindow, errorMsg, title, MB_OK );
```

I don't know how to make my program represent correctly the Unicode symbols, I have tried a lot of printf and scanf unicode versions and none of them works.

I have also tried setting the locale.

Could you help me? I am totally lost at this moment.

Comment: Do you tried functions declared in wchar.h?

Comment: Please check your BUILD TYPE first. TCHAR is defined as wchar_t in a Unicode build, but as char in a non Unicode build. Only wchar_t can handle Unicode properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you receive is `L"auszuf\\u00FChren"`, written in C source notation, which comes out as "auszuf\u00FChren".

You will need an extra layer of unescaping such that the sequence `\u00FC` is transformed into the umlaut `ü`. The follwoing example implements a (very rough) unescaping mechanism for C string syntax for both UNICODE and ASCII builds in C:

```
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef UNICODE
#define stprintf swprintf
#else
#define stprintf sprintf
#endif

static int hexdigit(TCHAR c)
{
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') return c - '0';
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'f') return c - 'a' + 10;
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F') return c - 'A' + 10;
    return -1;
}

static TCHAR hexcode(TCHAR const **p, int n)
{
    TCHAR uc = 0;

    while (n--) {
        int d = hexdigit(*(*p)++);

        if (d < 0) return 0xfffd;
        uc = (uc << 4) + d;
    }
    return uc;
}

/*
 *      Resolve C escapes in src and write up to n - 1 characters 
 *      to str, which is zero-terminated. Returns number of 
 *      characters in str, not counting the trailing NUL.
 */
int unescape(TCHAR *str, int n, const TCHAR *src)
{
    TCHAR *p = str;
    TCHAR *end = p + n - 1;

    while (*src) {
        if (p == end) break;

        if (*src == '\\') {
            src++;

            switch (*src++) {
            case 'n':   *p++ = '\n'; break;
            case 't':   *p++ = '\t'; break;
            case '\\':  *p++ = '\\'; break;
            case '\'':  *p++ = '\''; break;
            case '"':   *p++ = '\"'; break;
            case '0':   *p++ = '\0'; break;            
            case 'x':   *p++ = hexcode(&src, 2); break;                         
            case 'u':   *p++ = hexcode(&src, 4); break;

            /* Ignore octal notation and non-printable chars */
            }
        } else {
            *p++ = *src++;
        }
    }

    *p = '\0';
    return p - str;
}

#define MAXBUF 80

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    TCHAR *title_esc = TEXT("Speicherplatz ungen\\u00FCgend");
    TCHAR *fmt_esc = TEXT("Es stehen nur %d MB zur Verf\\u00FCgung!");
    TCHAR title[MAXBUF];
    TCHAR fmt[MAXBUF];
    TCHAR msg[MAXBUF];

    unescape(title, MAXBUF, title_esc);
    unescape(fmt, MAXBUF, fmt_esc);
    stprintf(msg, fmt, 17);

    MessageBox(NULL, msg, title, MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

There is probably already a cleaner and better implemented API function for this, but I couldn't find it.